# Pygame,shooting bullets using vectors

Tags: vector, pygame

Ok so all night me and 5 other guys have been working on a project for our pygame module.Our lecturer hasn't given us any programs to reference from he has just throw a bunch of code at us (without commenting) and expecting us to understand it.We only started python since the start of september.We really need some help.

So we have one human player which is controlled by W A S & D and 15 random dots moving around the screen.We need to use vectors(which we have never used) to shoot at the random dots.

Please someone help.

edit code added~

`import pygame

class Terminator(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, (255, 0, 0), (10, 10), 10, 0)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.dx = screen.get_width()/2
        self.dy = screen.get_height()/2
        self.rect.center = (self.dx, self.dy)
        self.speed = 5
        self.screen = screen

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (self.dx, self.dy)

    def MoveLeft(self):
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.dx += 0
        else:
            self.dx -= self.speed

    def MoveRight(self):
        if self.rect.right > self.screen.get_width():
            self.dx += 0
        else:
            self.dx += self.speed

    def MoveUp(self):
        if self.rect.top <0:
            self.dy += 0
        else:
            self.dy -= self.speed

    def MoveDown(self):
        if self.rect.bottom > self.screen.get_height():
            self.dy += 0
        else:
            self.dy += self.speed



<code>


humansprite.py

<pre>
import pygame
import random
import math

class Humans(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((16, 16))
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, (0, 0, 255), (8, 8), 8, 0)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.dx = random.randrange(0, screen.get_height())
        self.dy = random.randrange(0, screen.get_width())
        self.screen = screen
        self.speed = 1
        self.alive = True


    def update(self):
        self.rect.centerx -= self.dx
        self.rect.centery -= self.dy
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.rect.left = self.screen.get_width()
        self.rect.centery = random.randrange(0, self.screen.get_height())
        self.dy = random.randrange(-2, 2)
        self.dx = random.randrange(1, 4)

<code>

seekandDestory.py
<pre>
import pygame
from TerminatorSprite import Terminator
from humansSprite import Humans

pygame.init()


def checkKeys(myData):
    (event, ship) = myData
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        print 'LEFT'
        ship.MoveLeft()
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        print 'RIGHT'
        ship.MoveRight()
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        print 'UP'
        ship.MoveUp()
    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        print 'DOWN'
        ship.MoveDown()




def main():

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Seek and Destroy")

    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))


    terminator = Terminator(screen)
    humans = []
    for people in range(15):
        people = Humans(screen)
        humans.append(people)


    terminatorGroup = pygame.sprite.Group(terminator)
    humanGroup = pygame.sprite.Group(humans)


    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    keepGoing = True
    pygame.key.set_repeat(10, 10)
    while keepGoing:
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                myData = (event, terminator)
                checkKeys(myData)
        #if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(terminator, humanGroup, False):

        terminatorGroup.clear(screen, background)
        terminatorGroup.update()
        terminatorGroup.draw(screen)
        humanGroup.clear(screen, background)
        humanGroup.update()
        humanGroup.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()



    pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
<code>`

Comment: [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43953216/6220679) which demonstrates how you can use pygame vectors to move sprites.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished up [this set of examples](http://github.com/ternus/pygame-examples) last night! Check out the Lunar Lander example, especially [the way I'm handling vectors in lunarlander.py](https://github.com/ternus/pygame-examples/blob/master/lunarlander.py#L44) - it provides a class, `V`, for vector management.

What you'll probably need is a sprite for your guy with a vector representing his speed (moment-to-moment, probably 0) and angle, then a sprite for each random dot with a similar vector and angle. When you shoot, create a new sprite with a vector whose angle matches the current angle your guy is facing and magnitude matches the speed of the bullet. Then, in the `update()` method, move each sprite (bullet, random-dot). Very similar to what I'm doing in `lunarlander.py`.

Good luck! If you've just started Python, that's a tough assignment. Happy coding!

Comment: The code looks good. But why do you call `Lander`'s parent class as the last statement rather than first?

Comment: I'm used to `return super(superclass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` as an idiom. Is that actually incorrect?

Comment: Do you have any links about it? I tried searching to verify either way, but it doesn't search well. Using `super` with `kwargs` like that is normal. But if it's the last statement, I thought if you happen to modify any variables that `superclass` has, it could undo/set them after your code.

Comment: Ok thanks,but I can barely make heads or tails of that code as Ive only been doing python a month and or so.

Comment: OK. You'll probably have better luck if you post your code and ask a more specific question, then.